# Creating nested using comprehension and range

Tags: python, loops, matrix, list-comprehension

I'm trying to create a nested list from range using list comprehension.

So far, I coded the `for` loop version of this. Is there any way I can do so using list comprehension?

Here is my code:

```
matrix = []
start = 1
for x in range(11, 51, 10):
    item = list(range(start, x))
    matrix.append(item)
    start = x


[print(row) for row in matrix]
```

Result:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
 [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
 [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30]
 [31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40]]
```

Comment: Something like `np.arange(1, 41).reshape(4,10)` will get you there.

Comment: Thanks, so I can't do it using comprehension and range or without using something like np?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
matrix=[list(range(i*10+1, i*10+11)) for i in range(4)]

>>> print(matrix)

[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20], [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30], [31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40]]
```

Comment: Wow, it worked perfectly. And this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot.